# The flaw in what I consider as a flaw in Diffie-Hellman algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was going through the diffe-hellman  algorithm in cryptography .  So the algorithm apart the mathematicality it hinges on is as follows :

If $ p $ is a prime number and  $ g $ is another integer and $ a$ and $b$ are two integers  then

($ g^a $ $mod p )^b$ $mod $ $p $  =  ($ g^b $ $mod p )^a$ $mod $ $p $  ------$A$

I got the proof of it  but before going through its proof  I tried along the following lines :

let $g^a$ be $k_1$$p$ + $r_1$ where $r_1$ < $p$
and $g^b$ be $k_2$$p$ + $r_2$ where $r_2$ < $p$

so $g^a$ $mod$ $p$ =  $r_1^a$ $mod$ $p$

and $g^b$ $mod$ $p$ =  $r_2^a$ $mod$ $p$

Now similarly :

$(g^a$ $mod$ $p$)$^b$ $ mod p $ is ($r_1^a$)$^b$)$mod$$p$

and $(g^b$ $mod$ $p$)$^a$ $ mod p $ is ($r_2^a$)$^b$)$mod$$p$

If  $A$ is true then that means ($r_1^a$)$^b$)$mod$$p$ should be equal to ($r_2^a$)$^b$)$mod$$p$ which of course is not true given the random choice of $a$ and $b$ .

I think I had made a mistake somewhere while moving along these lines . Where is it that I erred ?

As TonyK points out the mistake was  the following :

$g^a$ $mod$ $p$ =  $r_1^a$ $mod$ $p$

It should have been $g^a$ $mod$ $p$ =  $r_1$ $mod$ $p$ .

So with this correction  :

$(g^a$ $mod$ $p$)$^b$ $ mod p $ is ($r_1$)$^b$)$mod$$p$

and

$(g^b$ $mod$ $p$)$^a$ $ mod p $ is ($r_2$)$^a$)$mod$$p$  .

How to reason out  ($r_1$)$^b$) being equal to  ($r_2$)$^a$) ?

Comment: Typesetting tip: use `g \bmod p` ($g \bmod p$) instead of `g mod p` ($g mod p$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your (first) mistake:

> so $g^a \bmod p = r_1^a\bmod p$

This should be

> so $g^a \bmod p = r_1\bmod p$

Comment: But in general , if $a$ $ \congr $ $b mod p$ then  $a$ can be expressed as  $ kp + b $ for some integer k , so $ a^n$ is $(kp+b)^n$ which on expansion   yields an expression which contains powers of $p$  in all terms + $ b ^n$ , so $a^n$ - $b^n$ is divisible by $p$ . Isn't it so ?

Comment: Found the mistake ... Editing it

Answer (score 0):

> How to reason out $r_1^b$ being equal to $r_2^a$ ?

Both are equal to $g^{ab}\bmod p$. Easy!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know what made me miss this